# KineticJS afterFrame doesn't run on loop

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I tried to have a reloading animation change values for my character. I want player.shots to go up by 1 every time the animation loops. However, it runs once and the animation continues Here is the code I have.

```
    gun.setAnimation('reload');
gun.afterFrame(6,function(){
        console.log('reload');
        player.shots++;
        if(player.shots > 5){
          gun.setAnimation('idle');
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, if an error occurs in the function it works like expected.

```
    gun.setAnimation('reload');
gun.afterFrame(6,function(){
        console.log('reload');
        player.shots++;
        if(player.shots > 5){
          gun.setAnimation('idle');
        }
        throw "reloading"
    }
```

This leads me to believe that afterFrame determines if it should run on the next iteration or not based on a return value.

Is there any nice workaround or parameter I need to add, or should I just keep intentionally causing an error to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do it, but I have submitted a pull request on github that will make returning true make it loop.

EDIT: New way to do it

```
sprite.on('indexChange', function(evt) {

});
```